# How to run a SQL query with a WITH clause with azureml-dataprep?

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I inherited from a colleague some SQL queries that make heavy use of the SQL WITH clause against a MS SQL database, but I can't seem to be able to run them and get the result in the form of pandas dataframes using `azureml-dataprep`.

As a simple example, consider e.g. the code

```py
import azureml.dataprep as dprep
import time

secret = dprep.register_secret(value="flowerpower", id="id")

db = dprep.MSSQLDataSource(server_name="myserver.net, 12345",
                           database_name="Flowers",
                           user_name="davide",
                           password=secret)
```

I then define two queries, which should be completely equivalent:

```py
flower_query = '''SELECT TOP (100) [Sepal.Length], [Sepal.Width]
                  FROM [Flowers].[Iris]'''

# unnecessarily convoluted, but still perfectly legit syntax:
flower_with_query = '''WITH I AS (SELECT TOP (100) [Sepal.Length], [Sepal.Width]
                           FROM [Flowers].[Iris]) 
                       SELECT * FROM I'''
```

The following "non-WITH" query runs without problems:

```py
flower_dataflow = dprep.read_sql(db, flower_query)
flower_df = flower_dataflow.to_pandas_dataframe()
```

The WITH variant

```py
flower_dataflow = dprep.read_sql(db, flower_with_query) # using the WITH query
flower_df = flower_dataflow.to_pandas_dataframe()
```

fails with

> ExecutionError:  Error Code: ScriptExecution.DatabaseQuery Failed
> Step: b1da84ed-e429-4752-ac98-4cb74b9ca114 Error Message:
> ScriptExecutionException was caused by DatabaseQueryException.
> 'MSSQL' encountered exception of with error code '156' while executing
> query 'SELECT * FROM (WITH I AS (SELECT TOP (100) [Sepal.Length],
> [Sepal.Width]
> FROM [Flowers].[Iris])  SELECT * FROM I) as
> subquery'. SqlException class: 15. HResult: x80131904.
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an
> xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous
> statement must be terminated with a semicolon. Incorrect syntax near
> ')'.

From the error, it seems as if the library is prepending a `SELECT * FROM` to my original query (?), and that gives rise to problems.
Prepending a semicolon `;` to my `flower_with_query` is not good enough to solve, and when doing so I get

> 'MSSQL' encountered exception of with error code '102' while executing query 'SELECT * FROM (;WITH I AS (SELECT TOP (100)...

Is there a limitation to the set of queries that can be run through `azureml-dataprep`? If so, is there a workaround that allows to run successfully queries without any SQL refactoring? I am aware of ODBC drivers but I'd rather use a solution that needs the least possible configuration (`azureml-dataprep` excels at that I think).

I am using `azureml-dataprep-2.0.7` and `azureml-core-1.13.0`.

Comment: Have you tested the query directly against the db using `pyodbc`?

Comment: My colleagues'  queries run fine with pyodbc, I will check again tomorrow my toy example. I am confident both variants will execute fine though.

Comment: I agree it is very weird! What version of MS SQL?

Comment: I confirm that both queries run fine when using pyodbc with {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} firing queries from Win 10. MS SQL version of my db "myserver.net" is 15.0.4043.16.

Answer (score 3):

dataprep is deprecated. We recommend to switch over to azureml dataset for reading data from sqldb.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.dataset_factory.tabulardatasetfactory?view=azure-ml-py#from-sql-query-query--validate-true--set-column-types-none--query-timeout-30-

Comment: I didn't know about the deprecation, even though I was aware of Dataset. Just for my sanity though, was deprecation advertised anywhere? (I'm assuming that that "we" stands for MSFT :) Thanks!!